# Pick random number from list of array values captured during correlation in Loadrunner

Tags: c, arrays, loadrunner

I have correlated the values from my script and have captured into a list of array using `Ord=all`, now I wanted to display the values randomly and pass it to a file, in a certain format.
Can someone help me understand how random function is used in Loadrunner.

script:

```
web_reg_save_param("param", "rb=\\", "lb=\\", "Ord=all", LAST);
values:
param_1 = blah-blah
param_2 = blah-blah
```

and so on n on....

Comment: Why is this tagged as C

Comment: As Loadrunner is C based. functions used in Loadrunner are C

Comment: The default language is C for web virtual users.   VB and Java are also supported as languages for the tool

Answer (score 0):

> ... pass it to a file, ...

Greater than 99% of the time why people want to do this is because they intend to take a value as output generated by one virtual user type and pass it as input to another virtual user type.  In general this does not work for the following reasons:

- All parameter files are loaded into RAM at the beginning of the test, so a new value written to the tail end of a file will only show up in the next test, not the current test
- In a properly designed test virtual user types are distributed to different load generators.  This would mean that you would need to write the file to a common location for all of the virtual users to access, such as a shared network drive.   You would now be adding two extra finite resource calls to your virtual users, a network request and a disk write request.   This will slow your virtual users down, possibly introducing a bottleneck into your entire test design
- Let's be blunt, very few LoadRunner users have got the skills to manage tens, hundreds or thousands of users all reading, writing (and potentially deleting) records from the same file.   This is a non trivial programming operation.  By asking how to write the information to a file you have placed yourself in the skills arena where you don't have the programming maturity to be up to the task on this one.   In all likelihood you will introduce all sorts of delays due to locking as all of the users try to access the same time.
- HP includes a service to allow users to pass data from one user to another via a broker.   This is the Virtual Table Server (VTS).   VTS would then manage the locks and all of the reads, writes and deletes to its internal data files which simplifies the act of pasing data from one user to the another immensely.   VTS is a "use once" queue for passing data, so there is no reason why you could not also use a queue solution such as RabbitMQ or a Queue table in your database provider to accomplish the same task.   Just be sure to not use a queuing solution running on the same infrastructure as your application under test